# How do i display webviews in viewflipper?

Tags: android, xml, layout, webview, viewflipper

I am a noob to android development and i am trying to display a listview and multiple webviews within a view flipper. Before i added the webviews and listview the viewflipper xml was parsing and executing fine.  However, now eclipe is giving me the same "Element type "WebView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"." message for each child view in my viewflipper. I am at my wits end trying to figure out what is goin on.   any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#FFFFFF">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/twitter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/twitterlogo" >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/youtube"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
android:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/youtubelogo" >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/rss"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
android:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/rsslogo" >
</ImageButton>

<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/calendar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
android:background="@null"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageButton>

<ViewFlipper android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1" >
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webViewnews"android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" ></WebView>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/ListViewId" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"></ListView>          
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webViewcoinshows"android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" ></WebView>
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webViewyoutube"android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" ></WebView>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to clean your project.  If that doesn't work then clean up the structure a bit. Crtl+Shift+F should do the trick.